# Is it possible to embed Facebook apps on my own website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, but is it possible to embed Facebook apps on my own website pages?

I'm talking about custom apps, not any of the native functionality provided by the the API.

Thank you!

Ben

Comment: Ben, accept some answers or it will become more difficult for you to get help in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All the apps hosted in apps.facebook.com can be hosted on your own domain.

Comment: Your answer is correct but for some reason i though the OP was talking about putting (e.g.) Farmville in an iframe on his web page, which would probably not work

Comment: So does that mean if i write my own Facebook application i can use an iFrame to embed it within my page?

Comment: Igy is right. You can't export an app that you didn't make (Farmville etc.) into your website. Technically or legally. If you make your own, you can embed it onto your own domain as you please.

Comment: Sorry guys been off line for the day. Cool, do you knownif itsma simple copy paste iframe job? I'm looking for some docs online but not finding what I need!